# How make text at button under the icon?

Tags: qt

How make text at button  under the icon with qss ?

[image]

qustion how do it at QPushbutton, not at toolbutton.

Comment: one way is put text in the icon.

Comment: Have you tried smth. like "\nDelete"?

Comment: This i make with \n , QPushButton hv only right or left on text setting's :(

Answer (score 0):

There would be more solutions to your question but, I prefer to use QToolButton instead of using QPushButton and set `toolButtonStyle` property to `ToolButtonTextUnderIcon`. To do it fast in ui file right click on your QPushButton and choose morph into QToolButton.